# Deploying a .NET application and use Sybase Adaptive Server ADO.NET Data Provider

Tags: .net, deployment, sap-ase

I'm developing a Windows service with .NET framework 3.5. The key feature of the service is a connection made to a Sybase database which executes some stored procedures.

If I deploy my service on a machine where ASE is installed, it works fine.

But, when I deploy my service on a client machine, I get this message in the Event Viewer:

> Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient : Could not load code page for requested charset

Then I installed ASE on the client and the service works.

My question is if someone knows how to deploy the Adaptive Server ADO.NET Data Provider without using the GAC, as explained [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.0215/html/adonet2155/Registering_deploying_adodotnet_dev.htm)?

It's not clear what package I have to install, I'm installing [this download](http://www.sybase.com/ase_1500devel), but I just need only the client, not the entire package.

If someone is experienced working with Sybase, I will thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

1. Create a `C:\Sybase` folder.
2. Copy the `charsets` folder into this folder.
3. Restart IIS